# How to show the number of processed files in Gulp

Tags: gulp

I'm evaluating Gulp as an alternative to Grunt and have the following problem.
Typically all grunt plugins (jshint, jscs, uglify, etc) show the number of processed files in a task but this seems not to be the case in any of the Gulp plugins.
Is there a specific reason for this and how would I be able to have the same functionality in Gulp.

Just as an example:

```
gulp.task('lint', function () {
    return gulp.src('./js/*.*/*.js')
        .pipe(jshint('.jshintrc'))
        .pipe(jshint.reporter('default'))
        .pipe(jshint.reporter('fail'))
        .pipe(jscs('./.jscsrc'));
});
```

would only show

```
[22:36:43] Finished 'lint' after 2.77 s
```

but I would like to see the number of files that has been processed as it is shown by Grunt

```
Running "jshint:all" (jshint) task
>> 42 files lint free.
Running "jscs:src" (jscs) task
>> 42 files without code style errors.
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason gulp plugins don't do this is that plugins are designed to have no knowledge of the number of files.  They (almost always) see just one file at a time, passed in through the streams.

Grunt works sort of like this (using Less/CSS for a simple example):

1. All Less Files are passed in to Less and processed, then saved to a new location as CSS
2. Once every file has been processed by Less, all CSS Files are run through a CSS linter
3. Once every file has been linted, all CSS Files are compressed via a CSS optimizer then saved back out
4. Done.

Each step has to wait for the previous state to complete fully.

Gulp works more like this:

1. Start loading Less files.
2. As soon as a file is found, pass it to Less
3. As soon as Less is done, run the in-memory CSS through a CSS linter

   - Less will now start on the next file if there is one
4. As soon as the linter finishes, run the in-memory CSS through the optimizer

   - The linter will now start on the next file if Less is done
5. Now write the file out to the destination.

   - The optimizer can start on the next file after the linter
6. Repeat 2-5 until all files have been run through the process.

Steps 2-5 can all be happening at the same time, each on a different file.

That being said, it's possible to have a plugin that keeps track of the number of files, which would count until the stream ends and then print it out.  (This probably won't work on a continuous stream like that created by `gulp-watch`, because those streams never end.)

I did not see an existing plugin that would do this, but you might could make one in your gulpfile in a similar fashion to this (untested):

```js
// need to run: npm i --save-dev 'through'
var through = require('through');

function count(message) {
  var count = 0;

  function countFiles(file) {
    count++;
  }

  function endStream() {
    console.log(count + ' ' + message || 'files processed.');
    this.emit('end');
  }

  return through(countFiles, endStream);
};
```

Use it like this:

```js
.pipe(jshint('.jshintrc'))
.pipe(jshint.reporter('default'))
.pipe(jshint.reporter('fail'))
.pipe(count('files lint free.'))
```

Comment: This works but not as expected... [Please see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27331941/how-do-i-count-the-number-of-files-in-a-gulp-stream)

Answer (score 1):

As of May 2015, you can:

- use **gulp-count** to count number of files, or
- **gulp-debug** to list all files and count them.

Btw, gulp-count counts only Files, but gulp-debug counts and lists both Files and Folders.

Answer (score 0):

It's easy!

```
const glob = require('glob');
const search = './__tests__/*.js';
const files = glob.sync(search);
console.log(files.length);
```