# How to tell Gulp when a task is finished?

Tags: javascript, node.js, gulp, node-modules

I am trying to write a gulp plugin which will count the number of files in the stream. [I used this as a starting point](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25587124/3959480):

```
function count() {

  var count = 0;

  function countFiles(data) {
    count++;
    // added this as per official docs:
    this.queue(data);
  }

  function endStream() {
    console.log(count + " files processed");
    // not doing this as per original post, as it "ends" the gulp chain:
    //this.emit("end");
    // so doing this instead as per official docs:
    this.queue(null);
  }

  return through(countFiles, endStream);
}


module.exports = count;
```

And here is a sample task:

```
gulp.task("mytask", function () {
  gulp
    .src("...files...")
    .pipe(count());                // <--- here it is
    .pipe(changed("./some/path"))
    .pipe(uglify())
    .pipe(rename({ extname: ".min.js" }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest(./some/path))
    .pipe(count());                // <--- here it is again
});
```

It works perfectly, except that it does not begin/end as expected:

```
[14:39:12] Using gulpfile c:\foo\bar\baz\gulpfile.js
[14:39:12] Starting 'mytask'...
[14:39:12] Finished 'mytask' after 9.74 ms
9 files processed
5 files processed
```

That means that the thing is running asynchronously and finishes after the task is complete. The docs say that you must use a callback or return a stream. It seems to be doing just that.

**How do I make this function behave?** Is it because I'm using the `through` rather than the `through2` plugin?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put `return` before `gulp` in your task.  You haven't provided any way for gulp to know when your stream is finished.

Comment: And those changes I made to your original source are OK? I changed it so I can use the plugin more than once. Should I carry on using `through` or `through2`?

Comment: Switch to through2 if you care, it probably doesn't matter.  If they work, the changes are OK!

Comment: It's a really useful plugin. You should consider adding it to your growing collection at GitHub! I often use it to see how many files are changed in a chain of pipes (sort of like in the e.g. above, i.e. before vs after).

Comment: @OverZealous Can you show us how to use lazypipe() here (http://stackoverflow.com/a/28774788/235415) to pull out the jshint and uglify from the build:js task so that they can be reused in normal build? Problem we are facing is with the local variable used in the task. Thank you.