# Prepend custom strings to JS files while concatenating

Tags: gulp, gulp-concat, gulp-uglify

I am trying to migrate our build process to gulp from existing custom bash build script. We concatenate several unminified opensource JS files like bootstrap, lazyload, ... and our own JS files. We uglify each JS file (removing their licenses as well) in an order, prepend custom license text to some of them as required and concatenate to create the output JS file. The custom license text are currently kept as strings in the bash script.

How to achieve this in gulp without creating intermediate files?
Will it also be possible to selectively avoid uglifying some JS scripts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I spent some time learning up gulp and it's plugins and here is a working version. The points here are using the foreach on each JS retrieved from the JSON config file, pushing the streams to an array and finally using merge on the array streams.

Here are the plugins used and the JSON structure defined:

```
var gulp = require('gulp');

var each = require('foreach');
var debug = require('gulp-debug');
var gulpif = require('gulp-if');
var jshint = require('gulp-jshint');
var uglify = require('gulp-uglify');
var concat = require('gulp-concat-util');

var es = require('event-stream');
var cache = require('gulp-cached');
var remember = require('gulp-remember');

// Structure that holds the various JS files and their handling
var Config = {
  js: {
    output_dir: 'path/to/output/file/',
    output_file: 'outputfile.js',
    src: [{
      name: 'bootstrap',
      src: ['path/to/bootstrap.js'],
      run_lint: false,
      run_uglify: true,
      license: '/* bootstrap license */'
    }, {
      name: 'lazyload',
      src: ['path/to/lazyload.js'],
      run_lint: false,
      run_uglify: true,
      license: '/* lazyload license */'
    }, {
      name: 'inhouse-js',
      src: ['path/to/inhouse/ih-1.js', 'path/to/inhouse/ot/*.js'],
      run_lint: true,
      run_uglify: true,
      license: ''
    }]
  }
}
```

The build task, with caching as we will be using it in development also:

```
gulp.task('build', ['build:js']);

gulp.task('build:js', function() {
  var streams = [];

  each(Config.js.src, function(val, key, array) {
    var stream = gulp.src(val.src)
      .pipe(cache('scripts'))
      .pipe(gulpif(val.run_lint, jshint('.jshintrc')))
      .pipe(gulpif(val.run_lint, jshint.reporter('jshint-stylish')))
      .pipe(gulpif(val.run_uglify, uglify({
                                     compress: {
                                       drop_console: true
                                     }
      })))
      .pipe(concat.header(val.license + '\n'));

    streams.push(stream);
  });

  es.merge.apply(this, streams)
    .pipe(remember('scripts')) // add back all files to the stream
    .pipe(concat(Config.js.output_file))
    .pipe(gulp.dest(Config.js.output_dir));
});
```

If you would like to debug, a good option will be to insert debug plugin like this example around the 'gulp-remember' plugin call above:

```
.pipe(debug({title: 'before remember:'}))
.pipe(remember('scripts')) // add back all files to the stream
.pipe(debug({title: 'after remember:'}))
```

And here's the watch task:

```
gulp.task('watch', function() {
  var watch_list = [];
  each(Config.js.src, function(val, key, array) {
    watch_list.push.apply(watch_list, val.src);
  });

  // Watch .js files
  var watcher = gulp.watch(watch_list, ['build']);

  watcher.on('change', function(event) {
    console.log('File '+ event.path +' was '+ event.type +', running tasks..');
    if (event.type === 'deleted') { // if a file is deleted, forget it
      delete cache.caches['scripts'][event.path];
      remember.forget('scripts', event.path);
    }
  })
});
```

You can use lazypipe() to reuse parts of the build:js task with normal build.

Comment: fwiw to you a year later, and for everyone else reading this: I don't think that this is a good approach for many reasons. 1) There is no separation of tasks. It's not possible to lint files without uglifying them. 2) No streams are ever returned, and done is never called, so gulp does not know when the tasks are completed (it may sometimes 'hang' for a long time doing nothing, even though it looks like all of the processing is done) 3) gulp-if is being used but it is not needed here.   ...etc.

Comment: i help npm package something like this https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-inject-string

Comment: @sabertabatabaeeyazdi Thanks. I have been using it, but haven't updated this answer above. Infact, the above code has been working successfully on my production server for last several years with slight updates; a side note.